# map2 in scala in Exception Handling

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
def map[B] (f: A=>B) : Option[B]

def flatMap[B] (f: A=>Option[B]) : Option[B] 

def map2[A,B,C] (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B]) (f: (A,B) => C) :Option[C] =
ao.flatMap(aa=>
  bo.map(bb=>
    (f(aa,bb))))
```

Here is the definition of map and flatMap in Exception Handling and I have this map2 formed on the basis of map and flatMap. It is really hard to understand the formation of map2. Can some one explain the role of flatMap and map in map2. Thank you

Comment: Is this exercise  from Functional Programming with Scala ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another attempt at explaining it. `Option` is a [Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) which in a simplified way might be seen as a generic container that hold some value(s).

`map` is a transformation operation that allows you to transform value(s) inside the monad using simple function on "raw" types.

`flatMap` is similar to `map` but is a bit more complicated: it allows you to transform value(s) inside the monad using a function that accepts "raw" value but returns an instance of the same monad and still as a result you get just a `Monad[B]` instead of `Monad[Monad[B]]` that would be generated by the `map`. In other words `flatMap` "flattens" the result.

So now what your `map2` does? It accepts 2 instances of `Option` monad and a function that transform "raw" pair of types into a single new "raw" type and return `Option` of that result type. Logically this is similar to `map` but to implement it you need a `flatMap`. To call your `f` you need to "unpack" both `ao` and `bo`. But monad doesn't provide a way to just "unpack" raw value. You might want to use just `map`. After all `map2` is logically similar to it! However, if you write

```
ao.map(aa =>
  bo.map(bb => f(aa,bb)))
```

as you might naively do, it wouldn't work as you might expect. The reason is that `bo.map(bb => f(aa,bb))` returns `Option[C]` (remember, there is no standard way to "unpack" a monad) and thus your function passed to `ao.map(aa => ...)` returns `Option[C]` and thus the result would be `Option[Option[C]]`. But this exactly where `flatMap` comes to the rescue! It allows you "unpack" this double `Option` into a simple `Option[C]`.

Obviously this explanation is quite naive but I hope it will help you get some intuition about what happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you add some syntactic sugar using a `for-comprehension` it suddenly becomes a lot more easy to read if you ask me:

```
def map2[A,B,C] (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B])(f: (A,B) => C): Option[C] = for {
  a <- ao
  b <- bo
} yield f(a,b)
```

Basically, we want to extract the `a` and the `b` of our two options and then apply our function `f` to get a `C`. `flatMap` allows us to do just that, by using a function from an `A` to an `Option[B]`. `map` then allows us to apply our function `f` to transform `(A,B)`to `C`.

Comment: Yes, I know this for comprehension but I want to know the process behind using flatMap and map because, in the end, the compiler desugars the bindings to flapMap calls, with the final binding and yield being converted to a call to map. right?

Comment: Yes, exactly `for` gets desugared to `flatMap` and `map`. I'm not exactly sure what your question is then. Are you asking why to use these two functions?

Comment: I'm asking this question because I'm still a novice in scala. Why do you write (f: (A, B) => C) within spearate brackets, and not with the other arguments. I mean, why it is not like -> (ao: Option[A], bo: Option[B], f: (A,B) => C) : Option[C] = ...

Comment: It's because of Scala Type inference. If you only use one parameter list, Scala can't infer the types of your function `f`.

Answer (score 0):

I think about things like this step by step from the result.

Firstly you know you eventually want a value of type A and a value of type B to pass to the function f.

Where does the A come from? We can access it by mapping over oa.

We can take that A and do the same to get B. mapping over ob gives us a B.

If you type this out in your IDE you will see a type error, you have an option option instead of an option.

This happened because that first map wraps its response as an option but so does the inner map. So by changing the outer map to flatMap you flatten it again.